# neo4j - Cypher query with REDUCE function throw Unknown identifier error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying a recommendation sample from the site http://gist.neo4j.org/?8173017.

After loading the movie data set from the site and try to run the  query

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[x:RATED]->(m:Movie)<-[y:RATED]-(p2:Person)
WITH  SUM(x.rating * y.rating) AS xyDotProduct,
      SQRT(REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(x.rating) | xDot + a^2)) AS xLength,
      SQRT(REDUCE(yDot = 0.0, b IN COLLECT(y.rating) | yDot + b^2)) AS yLength,
      p1, p2
MERGE (p1)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(p2)
SET   s.similarity = xyDotProduct / (xLength * yLength)
```

Throwing the following error

```
Unknown identifier `xDot`. 

Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

I am using neo4j 2.1.2

Comment: I just added the Movie Recommendations graph to a Neo4j 2.1.3 database and ran your query. It worked with no errors, creating 105 relationships and setting 210 properties. 15 nodes are linked via SIMILARITY relationships.

Comment: I just ran it in 2.1.2 and I get the unknown identifier xDot error.

Comment: I remember seeing this; I think it was just a bug in the Cypher parser in that specific version.

Comment: I downloaded 2.1.3 version and tried. Its working fine!! . thank you for the suggestion.